# Website as a bridge for Paypal payments

Tags: paypal

I would like to extend the services delivered by my website so that my website clients would be able to sell items and get directly paid.

My current Paypal implementation uses DoExpressCheckout which works fine when I am selling something for me.  I use the Paypal API using my Paypal ID, password...

As regard the possibility for my clients to also sell items through my website, I don't intend to charge this service and therefore, I would like to find a possibility to redirect Paypal payments to my clients.

The very first solution that came into my mind was to use my clients Paypal information so that it would be fully transparent for my website but this requires me to obtain my clients Paypal private information, which I don't like.

If now the payment for the items they sell is done via my Paypal account, I am charged with 3.4% + 0.5€ per transaction.  Then I need to transfer the money to their account, which as far as I understand the process would also charge me 3.4% + 0.5€ for the transfer.

Does anybody know a solution to allow my clients to sell items via my website and directly get paid via Paypal without involving my website in the transaction?

In advance, many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The people selling on your site just need to Grant API Permissions for your app on their PayPal account.  Then you can make the call on their behalf while still using your own API credentials.  You would just add their PayPal account ID or email address into the SUBJECT parameter of your API request along with the current un/pw/signature.

Your users can do this manually from within their PayPal account profile under API Access.  They would choose grant permissions, and then they would need to enter your API username, and then would check boxes for each permissions they need to grant (ie. express checkout, pro, etc.)

You can tie this into your app if you want using the [Permissions API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/permissions-service/integration-guide/PermissionsAbout/), and then you'd be using OAuth tokens and adding a token header to your requests.